# heapusage detects Memory leak possibly caused by printf

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am implementing a priority queue with linked list in C, however I am getting memory leaks when I print out my `pop` operations. I have another memory leak and I am trying to find it too.

As a side note, I am using `heapusage` by `d99kris` instead of `Valgrind`.

This is the heap summary when I use `printf`:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
in use at exit: 4112 bytes in 2 blocks
total heap usage: 10 allocs, 17 frees, 4536 bytes allocated
peak heap usage: 4256 bytes allocated
16 bytes in 1 block(s) are lost, originally allocated at:
LEAK SUMMARY:
definitely lost: 4112 bytes in 2 blocks
```

This is the heap summary without `printf`:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
in use at exit: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
total heap usage: 9 allocs, 10 frees, 440 bytes allocated
peak heap usage: 256 bytes allocated
LEAK SUMMARY:
definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
```

My `pop` function:

```
void *prio_q_pop(struct prio_q *q) {
     q->size--;
     struct elem *temp = q->first;
     (q->first) = (q->first)->next;
     void *asd = temp->datei;
     free(temp);
     return asd;
 }
```

And my `main` function where I call `printf`

```
struct prio_q *queue;
     char *s;
     int i;

     queue = prio_q_create();

     push(queue, "Bye World", 0);

     for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         s = prio_q_pop(queue);
         //printf("%s\n", s);
     }
     s = prio_q_front(queue);
     //printf("%s\n", s);
```

> reason

Problem is not caused by *my* code, It is the memory checker. The following program leaks 1 block with a heap usage of 2 allocs and 4 frees.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("omer");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the code leak more if you call `printf()` more?

Comment: 2 more `printf()` brings to 2 more frees

Comment: Show an [MCVE] please. Memory leaks could come from anywhere, and most likely not where you think

Comment: sure , thanks. any advice to trim or add code? @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: So... what about `int main() { printf("Hello, World\n"); return 0; }` Clearly *your* code has a leak. If you suspect `printf` does too, isolate it and test your hypothesis.

Comment: Start by reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And try [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) too. When you ask a question on StackOverflow, do provide some [MCVE]. For example, I don't know what your `push` is doing.

Comment: Thanks for that link, pretty nice article. However, I didn't want to post all my push, destroy etc. methods since it would be a chaos. I started with the places where I suspect most, then I would add/edit more codes to it. If nobody sees a suspicious line of code here, I can add my other methods too.

Comment: @aomerk But we don't care about the number of frees, we care about the number and size of leaked blocks, right? If you call `printf()` two more times, does the amount of allegedly leaked memory increase significantly? If you take out just one of of the `printf()` calls does the leaked memory decrease? It wouldn't be all that weird if `printf()` allocates a 4K buffer on the first call and never frees it, but it would be very surprising if every call leaks memory.

Comment: @Caleb please check last part of my edited question.

Comment: The posted code fails to properly handle when the queue pointer contains NULL..  At such a time/event, the code would be doing undefined behavior by access an offset from address 0

Comment: regarding: *There is nothing wrong with my code*  NEVER make that assumption.  it is (almost) always a problem with the users' code

Comment: edited, thanks. nice tipp

Comment: regarding the `Heap Summary`,  it shows 9 allocations and 10 frees.  Either some allocated memory is passed to `free()` more than once or the code is trying to `free()` heap memory that was never allocated.  This is an error in the user code.

Comment: @user3629249 okay

Comment: there is no check for whether or not any of your pointers are valid.  we don't know what's happening in the q_creat() function.   The fact that you have a single leak is bad to begin with. don't worry about the so called chaos, post something all of us can actually compile that reproduces your conditions. otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: Note: C library functions (although they do not actually leak memory) are not always obvious to a leak memory checker, (like valgrind).   Note: valgrind does have a (optional) parameter to ignore memory usage in C library functions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a false positive. If anything, the problem is that heapusage does not have good enough documentation. I recommend using a better leak checker like the leak sanitizer or Valgrind.

I created a file `test.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    puts("Hello, world!");
}
```

With leak sanitizer, no errors.

```
$ cc -fsanitize=leak -g test.c
$ ./a.out 
Hello, world!
```

With address sanitizer, no errors.

```
$ cc -fsanitize=address -g test.c
$ ./a.out 
Hello, world!
```

With Valgrind, no errors.

```
$ cc -g test.c
$ valgrind ./a.out
==189174== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==189174== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==189174== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==189174== Command: ./a.out
==189174== 
Hello, world!
==189174== 
==189174== HEAP SUMMARY:
==189174==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==189174==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==189174== 
==189174== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==189174== 
==189174== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==189174== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

With heapusage, a leak!

```
$ cc -g test.c                  
$ ./heapusage ./a.out
Hello, world!
==189005== Heapusage - https://github.com/d99kris/heapusage
==189005== 
==189005== HEAP SUMMARY:
==189005==     in use at exit: 1024 bytes in 1 blocks
==189005==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 1024 bytes allocated
==189005==    peak heap usage: 1024 bytes allocated
==189005== 
==189005== 1024 bytes in 1 block(s) are lost, originally allocated at:
==189005==    at 0x00007f99f0de56a7: malloc + 49
==189005==    at 0x00007f99f0a96a32: _IO_file_doallocate + 114
==189005==    at 0x00007f99f0aa4a46: _IO_doallocbuf + 70
==189005==    at 0x00007f99f0aa3da8: _IO_file_overflow + 472
==189005==    at 0x00007f99f0aa2e86: _IO_file_xsputn + 182
==189005==    at 0x00007f99f0a99033: _IO_puts + 211
==189005==    at 0x000055f667ee7655: 
==189005==    at 0x00007f99f0a502b1: __libc_start_main + 241
==189005==    at 0x000055f667ee755a: 
==189005== 
==189005== LEAK SUMMARY:
==189005==    definitely lost: 1024 bytes in 1 blocks
==189005==
```

### Analysis

Heapusage works by hooking malloc and free (and doesn't scan memory for pointers). Heapusage doesn't explain the advantages or disadvantages of this approach fully in the documentation. One advantage is that it's fast, but a disadvantage is that it's not precise.

In particular, I would call out heapusage as giving incorrect messages: the words "definitely lost" don't apply here!

If you want better error messages, use one of the tools recommended above: leak sanitizer or Valgrind (memcheck).

In general, I would also like to remind people that false positives are a fact of life with tools like these. Whether a program is "Valgrind clean" is a different question from whether the program is correct.

Comment: unfortunately, Valgrind still doesn't support Mojave, and I don't have access to my linux box right now. Really thanks a lot @Dietrich Epp. You literally helped apart from the most.

Comment: @aomerk: macOS developer tools ship with -fsanitize=leak support, I think, which is much faster than Valgrind anyway.

Comment: I tried built in Xcode instrument, it didn't show any errors but heapusage was the one confused me. About -fsanitze, I had no idea, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike Valgrind, `heapusage` does not track memory allocated by the C library for its own purposes. `printf` indirectly causes this as the stream `stdout` is line buffered to the terminal and fully buffered to a file. The stream buffer is allocated (by `printf` or any other output function) only when you actually produce output.

You can try and work around this limitation by making `stdout` unbuffered at the start of your `main` function. Try this for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf("omer\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If the above code still shows a leak, try this alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    setvbuf(stdout, buf, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);
    printf("omer\n");
    fclose(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice also that reading input from `stdin` will allocate a buffer for the input stream too. Any other stream opened by the program should have been closed prior to leaving the `main()` function. Closing a stream releases any memory allocated for it behind the scenes.

Comment: thanks a lot @chqrlie . I kind of lost my trust in heapusage since it wasted my afternoon, but I will keep your answer in mind.